# My sticky menu in firefox and IE doesn't work properly

Tags: html, css

So my sticky menu in word press is working fine on chrome but it messes up in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

I have tried to clear the cache and also have installed the latest versions of the browser.

Here's the customized css code I have used in global css

```
#mysticky-nav.myfixed{
position: fixed !important;
height: 130px !important;
}

#mysticky-nav.down{
margin-top:1px !important;
}

#mysticky-nav.wrapfixed{
margin-top:0px !important;
padding-top: 0px !important;
}


#mysticky-nav.wrapfixed.down .vce-single-image-inner{
padding-top: 0px !important;
}

#mysticky-nav.wrapfixed.up .vce-single-image-inner{
padding-top: 10px !important;
}

#mysticky-nav.wrapfixed.down .menu-menu-container a{    
color: #515769!important;
 }

 #mysticky-nav.wrapfixed.down .vce-single-image-inner img{  

 margin-top:10px !important; 
 content:url(https://pit147.sedenius.com/protected/wordpressvc/wp- 
 content/uploads/2019/07/logo-dark.png)  !important;
 }

 #mysticky-nav.wrapfixed.up .menu-menu-container a{ 
 color: #515769!important;
 }

#mysticky-nav.wrapfixed.up .vce-single-image-inner img{ 
content:url(https://pit147.sedenius.com/protected/wordpressvc/wp- 
content/uploads/2019/07/logo-dark.png)  !important;
}
```

I expect it to work it in firefox and IE the same way it is working on google chrome.

Comment: try with  `top` & `left` property

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you describe in more detail what the problem is in Firefox and IE/Edge (all versions?)? Do they suffer the same problem?

Comment: Please share a snippet with IE/EDGE problem Screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify top and left positions also.

```
#mysticky-nav.myfixed {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
```